# Why client_hostname is filled while log_hostname=off?

Tags: postgresql, hostname, postgresql-14, reverse-dns

I have to compare the postgresql server connection time with and without client_hostname resolution.

A server is already running in the domain, which have *log_hostname=on* in *postgresql.conf*. So a reverse DNS lookup is used to get hostname from client IP.

Now I just created a second postgresql server in the same domain, except this one have *log_hostname=off* in its config file. Nevertheless, the client_hostname is still filled when I query pg_stat_activity view.

If I check the documentation, I find :

> client_hostname text
>
> Host name of the connected client, as reported by a reverse DNS lookup of client_addr. This field will only be non-null for IP connections, **and only when log_hostname is enabled**.

Why turning it off does not seem to work? Am I missing another configuration?

On the server, Postgresql service has been restarted. The value of the parameter has been set correctly (I check with `show all;` query in pgAdmin)

This is what I get:
[host from pg_stat_activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YovjO.png)
While:
[log_hostname value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHnos.png)

Comment: Not in pg_hba.conf, in postgresql.conf surely?

Comment: Yes thanks @RichardHuxton, I just updated

Comment: I cannot reproduce that here with postgresql 14 - I toggled the setting on/off and saw `client_hostname` populate and be empty.

Comment: This is what I expected but.. I edited the end of my question to show you what I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it did not work.
In fact, the postgre server IP resolution is set to manual, and DNS addresses were manually filled. Removing these DNS IPs solved my issue